# Wordpress .htaccess issues causing blank page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am having some issues with my wordpress .htaccess file. For some reason it is causing the website to appear blank (no data is shown at all) and as soon as I rename the .htaccess folder the index page loads but no other page loads (due to the rewriting rules) so it is quite an issue. I can't live without it nor with it as it currently is.

This is what it currently looks like and I managed to pull up some error files

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Errors:

> [Sat Oct 05 00:43:55 2013] [11544193] [autoindex:error] [client
>   66.249.74.36:62083] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/chroot/home/content/93/11544193/html/wordpress/: No matching
>   DirectoryIndex
>   (default.html,default.htm,index.php,index.shtml,index.html,index.htm,home.html,home.htm,index.php5,welcome.html,welcome.htm)
>   found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options
>   directive

I have no clue on how to fix this issue so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How I read it, it tries to serve default.html, default.htm etc. but none of them exist. It then tries to show all files in the directory, but this is forbidden. Does the directory exist?

Comment: Have you placed above .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT or somewhere else? As per the code above it should be in DOCUMENT_ROOT of your server.

Comment: It is within the DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: You can also try enable the directory index by adding `Options +Indexes` to your `.htaccess` and check if you get a file listing.

Comment: Nope, I am not getting anything even with this enabled. I think it might be wp-supercache plugin because I just added it to another wordpress site and it had the same problem. Is it possible that this is the cause?